# How to translate react-router Route paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-intl

My application has more than one locale (it, en).

I need to translate all the routes. For example I have the terms and condition page that has to paths (one per locale):

- `it/termini`
- `en/terms`

I need than to do something like:

```
// routes.js

const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="(it/termini)(en/terms)" component={TermsPage} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Route>
)
```

As you can see this funky solution is not so good for the scalability of the application.

Answer (score 6):

My current approach with routes localization is to deal with them as I do with any localized content. 
In your case I would do:

```
// routes.js

function createRoutes(language) {
   /*
     You'll probably have more work to do here, 
     such as sub-routes initialization
     component's type selection logic, etc.

     @note: _t(key, language) is your 
            translation function
   */

   return (
       <Route 
          key={language} 
          path={_t("it/termini", language)} 
          component={TermsPage} 
       />
   )
}

let localizedRoutes = supportedLanguages.map(createRoutes)

const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
    {localizedRoutes}
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Route>
)
```

Then you can specify them in your translation files just as any other string, including any parameter:

```
// en.js

module.exports = {
//...
  "it/termini" : "en/terms",
  "it/profilo/:userId" : "en/profile/:userId"
//...
}
```

You can also assemble them on the fly before your routes are defined, associating them to the corresponding translation key.

In this way **it/termini** becomes just the key of your translated URL, you could also use something not resembling the underlying URL like **terms-page-url**.

This method also allows you to differentiate route components and/or sub routes per language, which is an added bonus. Just implement the logic inside your mapping function (or where it's appropriate for your application).

Comment: on the `return (<Router key={language` part, you mean `<Route`?

Comment: Yes, he did mean `Route`

Comment: With the i18next package, the `_t` function should be used like that: `i18n.t("it/termini", { lng: language })`